# Why in JAGS is the value of a node not always available?

Tags: r, statistics, jags

I'm new to JAGS, but after searching I haven't found a solution or an explanation for this behaviour. Basically, depending on if (and where) I pass in `0` values to a multinomial distribution, predictions from that distribution can be missing. I've simplified this down as much as I can. Here's a model I want to run:

`test.bugs`

```
data{
  for(i in 1:2){
    N[i] <- sum(counts_known[i, 1:6])
  }
}
model {
  for(i in 1:2){
    pi[i, 1:6] ~ ddirich(alpha[1:6])
  
    counts_known[i, 1:6] ~ dmulti(pi[i, 1:6], N[i])
    
    N_unknown[i] ~ dpois(N[i])
    counts_unknown[i, 1:6] ~ dmulti(pi[i, 1:6], N_unknown[i])
    
    # Example of trouble (yes, I could just access N_unknown here but this is a simplified example)
    # summation[2] may not exist
    summation[i] <- sum(counts_unknown[i, 1:6])
  }
}
```

My problem is that, depending on which order I pass in the data for the columns of `counts_known`, `summation[2]` may not exist in the output.

R code to run this:

```
library(rjags)

# This works fine
data <- list(
  alpha = rep(1/6, 6),
  counts_known = matrix(c(
    2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,0,0,4
  ), nrow=2, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
  
)
model <- jags.model("test.bugs", data=data, n.chains=1)
summary(coda.samples(model, variable.names=c("summation", "counts_unknown"), n.iter=1000))
# Output for counts_unknown and summation exist


# Swap columns 5 and 6 to see problem
data <- list(
  alpha = rep(1/6, 6),
  counts_known = matrix(c(
    2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,0,4,0
  ), nrow=2, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
  
)
model <- jags.model("test.bugs", data=data, n.chains=1)
summary(coda.samples(model, variable.names=c("summation", "counts_unknown"), n.iter=1000))
# Output for most of the counts_unknown and summation[1] exist; about a half of the time summation[2] and counts_unknown[2, 5:6] are missing
# If you see summation[2] on first try, try running the previous line of code again a few times
```

Based on the help page for `coda.samples` I know that the reason `summation[2]` is disappearing in the second example is that it can have NAs, which are dropped by default when handed, but that just leads to the questions of

1. Why is it generating NAs in the first place?
2. What is different between the two examples that causes the first one to seemingly work when in practice it's the same data, just reordered?

Also as a side-note, if I run `coda.samples` with `na.rm=FALSE` and look directly at the samples a `NaN` sometimes appear for those suspect columns.

Thanks for any help, and I'm running JAGS 4.3.0.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I suspect that few people reading this forum are prepared to answer this since it is pretty specialized. My advice is to try a JAGS-specific forum, or the r-help mailing list, or maybe stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to posting questions on here and assumed that correctly tagged questions would end up being seen by the other Stack Exchange sites, so I'll try that.

Comment: No problem, good luck.